# Does the new specialist after a crew change retain saved unspent AP from the previous turn?

Tags: flash-point

The rules say "The player's Firefighter has the AP (less the 2AP required for a crew change)...." If I effect a crew change and had Action Markers from unspent AP on my previous turn, do I get to keep those for the new character I am using? The strict literal reading of the rules implies no, and the story aspect reasonably would argue no, but it would certainly help me save victims!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, the strict literal reading of the rules says **yes** (keep them).  Everything in the general section (p4) says the AP saved applies to "the player" not the Firefighter.  Nothing I read in the crew change rules negates this.